# Looping through DataFrame via zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using this code to loop through a dataframe:

```
for r in zip(df['Name']):
   #statements
```

How do I identify a particular row in the dataframe? For example, I want to assign a new value to each row of the Name column while looping through. How do I do that?
I've tried this:

```
for r in zip(df['Name']):
   df['Name']= time.time()
```

The problem is that every single row is getting the same value instead of different values.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in the assignment:

```
df['Name']= time.time()
```

This says to grab the current time and assign it to every cell in the `Name` column.  You reference the column vector, rather than a particular row.  Note your iteration statement:

```
for r in zip(df['Name']):
```

Here, `r` is the row, but you never refer to it.  That makes it highly unlikely that anything you do within the loop will affect an individual row.

---

Putting on my "teacher" hat ...

Look up examples of how to iterate through the rows of a Pandas data frame.

Within those, see how individual cells are referenced: that technique looks a lot like indexing a nested list.

Now, alter your code so that you put the current time in *one* cell at a time, one on each iteration.  It will look something like

```
df.at[row]['Name'] = time.time()
```

or

```
row['Name'] = time.time()
```

depending on how you define `row` in your iteration.

Does that get you to a solution?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `'` in your 3rd code snippet.

Comment: I would use `df.at[row, name] = ` or something like that

Comment: @khuynh: Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: okay, now that you gave away the remaining access clue ... :-)  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following also works:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ['Bob', 'Dylan', 'Rachel', 'Mark'],
                        'age': [23, 27, 30, 35]})

# iterate through each row in the data frame
col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('name') # this is so we can use iloc

for i in df.itertuples():
    df.iloc[i[0], col_idx] = time.time()
```

<s>So, essentially we use the index of the dataframe as the indicator of the position of the row. The first index points to the first row in the dataframe, and so on.</s>

<s>**EDIT**: as pointed out in the comment, using `.index` to iterate rows is not a good practice. So, let's use the number of rows of the dataframe itself. This can be obtained via `df.shape` which returns a tuple `(row, column)` and so, we only need the row `df.shape[0]`.</s>

**2nd EDIT**: using `df.itertuples()` for performance gain and `.iloc` for integer based indexing.

Additionally, the official `pandas` doc recommends the use of `loc` for variable assignment to a `pandas` dataframe due to potential `chained indexing`. More information here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: `for i in df['name'].index:` is a common pandas anti-pattern.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. did not know it was a pandas anti-pattern. is it because it might cause problem when the index of the df is not `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on`?

Comment: No, it's because it's slow. You generally don't want to loop over a dataframe, but when you do, you should use `itertuples()` and you should not set single elements with `.loc` either (again, slow)

Comment: sorry just confirming, you should or you should not set single elements with `.loc`?

Comment: Sorry, should not. And looping over `for i in range(df.shape[0]):` is not correct (although it would at least be *correct* if not slow if you use `iloc`)

Comment: i updated my answer to include your feedback, thank you for sharing the concept.